# Filtering a List of Reports in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm on CRM 2011, viewing a Reports View.

The users can click "Reports" and see all reports on the system, via this view.

I'm trying to remove one particular report from this view via a filter, and I'm having a little difficulty.

If I select the report, click edit, and scroll down to the Categorization section, the "Display In" field shows "Forms for related record types" only.  This seems like it would remove it from this list, but it doesn't.

So I'm trying to add a filter that displays only the Reports with the "Display In" set to "Reports Area" - this should display all of the other reports.  But I can't find the "Display In" field when I create the criteria for this filter, under the Report entity or anything.

Where is the Display In field located?  If it's not something I can use in a filter, what is the recommended way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view on the Report entity. Define a filter for the view filtering on the related item **Report Visibilities**.

[image: This is what the filter should look like]